# Reactive statement being executed when child reactive statement changes?

Tags: svelte

I have two reactive statements in Svelte. When the child statement changes (based on some input), the parent statement (statement on which the child statement depends on) is also triggered. Check the following snippet:

```
<script>
    const options = [
        {key: 'one'},
        {key: 'two'},
        {key: 'three'},
    ];

    // NOTE: initialOption may be obtained reactively from somewhere like the query string.
    $: initialOption = options[0];
    $: selectedOption = initialOption;

    $: console.log('initialOption reactivity:', initialOption);
    $: console.log('selectionOption reactivity:', selectedOption);
</script>

<select bind:value={selectedOption}>
    {#each options as opt}
    <option value={opt}>{opt.key}</option>
    {/each}
</select>
```

https://svelte.dev/repl/bdc48c75acf94a9ca13da377b7cd8f19?version=3.20.1

If you run the snippet above, each time you try to select from the drop-down (which is bound to `selectedOption`), the `initialOption` assignment seems to be re-triggered, why? Is this expected behavior?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is two-fold:

- you're assigning objects, which in javascript are assigned by reference and not by value, to your reactive variables
- one of these variables is also bound (in a two-way binding) to the `value` property of your `select` element

When you interact with your `select` input, you update the value of `selectedOption`, which in turns updates `initialOption` (because both variables are references to the same object).

You have two ways to solve this issue:

1. use scalars instead of objects in your option array
2. bind to a regular variable instead of a reactive one, and instead use reactive code to initialize the variable

Both approaches are demonstrated [in this REPL](https://svelte.dev/repl/e4b8b407e5f246398feff0b7eb4a10b8?version=3.20.1)

Comment: Since the `selectedOption` is the same reference as `initialOption`, then when we change `selectedOption` we are indirectly triggering the reactive statement for `initialOption`?

Comment: @DanielRS yes, exactly, at least that's my understanding in light of the way the same code behaves when you use strings rather than objects, or when you keep using objects but make one of these two variables non-reactive.