# bind:value with #each cause reactive statement be executed

Tags: svelte

I have route with constantly changing PageData, and I want to update some of page state when this data changes. So I'm having the following code:

```
    export let data
    $: {
        console.log('PageData changed', data)
        parseOptions(data)
        resetOptions()
    }
```

As you can see the $ block has no variables mentioned except data. So it should be called only when data changes.

I also have the following HTML block:

```
        <select multiple name="filter" bind:value={providerIds}>
            {#each data.merchants as merchant, i (merchant.id)}
                <option value={i}>{merchant.name}</option>
            {/each}
        </select>
```

ProviderIds is simple array, nothing fancy. It's not even used anywhere. Merchant is also array inside PageData.

And here is what puzzles me: selecting any option in this select, with #each and bind:value causes $ to be executed. I've experimentally came to conclusion that either #each of bind:value are the reasons. Since if you have fixed options, you can easily select it. If you remove bind:value you also can select without triggering any side effects ( this select is useless then although ).

Can somebody please explain what is the reason of such strange behaviour or how can it be fixed?

Comment: Does this answer your question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61351613/reactive-statement-being-executed-when-child-reactive-statement-changes?rq=2

Comment: The situtation is slightly different if I understand this correctly. There reactive statement sets by reference in a two-way binding. In my case I bind select value to a value that is not connected to data in any way. It is also not referenced in functions that are called inside $ block.

Comment: Can you reproduce this in a REPL? https://svelte.dev/repl/1651a8d7f673489482f3b53fc4610c5d?version=3.58.0

Comment: I couldn't reproduce this in a REPL, might be due to the fact that the data is not static variable, but the pagedata from +page.server.ts, but I don't know how this causes the difference. Anyway suggested answer helped.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is a bug, see [this issue](https://github.com/sveltejs/svelte/issues/8243).

You may be able to work around this by not using a binding. You would only pass in `value` and handle the `change` event to get new values out. Select elements have a `selectedOptions` property which you could use to determine the new value.